# How GCM communicates with actual device using the Registration Id

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Hi am working on GCM and i have implemented that easily but am stuck at one part that how GCM use that registration Id to communicate with a device i.e how registration id is used or in simple words how GCM push that message to the device, is there a socket connection developed or if there is broadcast who is firing that broad cast and how? All in all i want to know that how GCM communicate with my device that is in a VPN how GCM finds my device.
I am doing the RND and this is the last point which is not clear.

Thanks

Comment: have you read the [GSM Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html) ??? Every thing is clear in their docs.

Comment: than tell me the inner working that how GCm finds your device if you know the answer than write it

Comment: what does you mean by gcm finds your device????

Comment: i mean when my application server send message to GCM to send this message to device what actually the GCM do to find my device to send that sms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that GCM actually sends data or message to your mobile using Google Play application installed on your phone that is why it is mandatory to have Google play app on your phone to get GCM working.

Please share if any one got some update on this

Answer (score 0):

While I do not know for sure (is it even documented?) I'd guess that Google keeps track of the Google Account linked to the registration ID in a database. They look up that Google Account when a message is queued to be sent from their servers to the device, and because your phone is connected to Google Servers (indicated by non-white signal colors for wifi and cell strength indicators in the navigation bar on Android 2.3+) they can send it directly to the desired device.